# $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\Omega)$ is dense in $L^\infty (\Omega)$ w.r.t. the weak topology $\sigma(L^\infty, L^1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, smooth-functions, dense-subspaces

I'm trying to prove a result mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768010/c-c-infty-omega-is-dense-in-l-infty-omega-with-respect-to-the-to) thread, i.e.,

> Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$. Then $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\Omega)$ is dense in $L^\infty (\Omega)$ w.r.t. the weak topology $\sigma(L^\infty, L^1)$.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is correct?

---

**Proof** We have $L^\infty =(L^1)^*$. Let $T: L^\infty \to \mathbb R$ be a linear function that is continuous w.r.t. the weak topology of $\sigma(L^\infty, L^1)$. By [Proposition 3.14.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367331/let-varphie-star-to-mathbb-r-be-linear-and-continuous-in-sigmae-star) in Brezis's [Functional Analysis](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7.pdf?pdf=button), there is $u \in L^1$ such that
$$
T (f) = \langle f, u \rangle = \int_\Omega u f \quad \forall f \in L^\infty (\Omega).
$$

Assume $T = 0$ on $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\Omega)$.  By *Corollary 1.8.* in the same textbook, it suffices to prove that $T =0$ on $L^\infty (\Omega)$.

> [Corollary 4.24](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667207/corollary-4-24-in-breziss-functional-analysis) Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$. Let $u \in L_{\text{loc}}^1 (\Omega)$ such that
> $$
> \int_{\Omega} uf =0 \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_c^\infty (\Omega).
> $$
> Then $u=0$ a.e. on $\Omega$.

It follows from above corollary that $u=0$ a.e. on $\Omega$ and thus $T \equiv 0$. This completes the proof.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you so much for your verification!